# iphone - presenting an alertview with the right orientation

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have to present an alertview when my app starts. My app supports both landscape modes.

Despite the landscape mode the device is when the app starts the alertview always shows in portrait.

I have tried to use the accelerometer to detect the interface orientation before the orientation notification and I have the correct orientation 2 seconds before the alertview showing.

Then, I use this code to set the status bar to a different orientation, hoping the alertview will follow...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

or left, depending on the landscape mode.

Nothing works.

Is there a way to force the alertview to respect the orientation?

The point here is this: I cannot set one landscape orientation in particular for the status bar, I have to detect the orientation the device is on and then set the status bar orientation.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Using the code you described, I'm able to create a simple application that shows a UIAlertView in landscape. I've put it here: http://www.thermoglobalnuclearwar.com/stuff/Example.zip

Comment: thanks, but you are fixing the orientation on the delegate. You cannot do that. My application (for iPad) was rejected by Apple by doing this. You have to detect in which landscape the user is on and set the status bar accordingly. If the user is not on any landscape than you can set one landscape left or right. The point is setting the statusbar orientation after detecting the orientation the device is on. But you will soon discover that at that point on the delegate, the orientation notification is not working yet....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your app using a UITabBarController or a UINavigationController?? Try calling the alert from the rootViewController , which may be a UITabBarController or any other rootController.
Dont show the alert from the immediate screen (or subview). Call [alert show] by overriding UITabBarController and from inside it.

i hope I got your problem right

Cheers,

Harikant Jammi